# TypeError: fns[(x * 2)] is not a function

Tags: javascript

so i have a homework problem need to solve .
The requirement is just fix the code so console show true

```
 var x = 2,
 fns = [];

(function () {
  var x = 5;

  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  //  write here 
  }
})();

// DO NOT MODIFY BELOW CODE
console.log(x * 2===fns[x * 2]());
// console must show true
```

the console output is

> Uncaught TypeError: fns[(x * 2)] is not a function

I try to rewrite function as it one of element in array but console still show error.
I rewrite the `fns[x * 2]()` to `fns[x * 2]` and the console show return false (which is fine cause at least it not throw error )  but cant modify it according to the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of the array needs to be a function that returns its current index in the array:

```js
var x = 2,
  fns = [];

(function() {
  var x = 5;

  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    fns[i] = () => i;
  }
})();

// DO NOT MODIFY BELOW CODE
console.log(x * 2 === fns[x * 2]());
// console must show true
```

Make sure to declare the index variable with `let`, not `var` (`var` [has problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)).

Or, more functionally:

```js
const fns = Array.from(
  { length: 5 },
  (_, i) => () => i
);

let x = 2;
// DO NOT MODIFY BELOW CODE
console.log(x * 2 === fns[x * 2]());
// console must show true
```

Comment: many thank , still new to javascript and the function javascript make my brain hurt

Answer (score 0):

You need a closure with an IIFE which takes the value.

```js
var x = 2,
    fns = [];

(function() {
    var x = 5;

    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        fns[i] = function (v) {
            return function () { return v; };
        }(i);
    }
})();

// DO NOT MODIFY BELOW CODE
console.log(x * 2 === fns[x * 2]());
// console must show true
```